# Safari shows the contents of JSON files instead of downloading them

Tags: javascript, json, safari

I have javascript code that generates a link that, when clicked, is supposed to download a JSON file. The generated link is something like:

```
<a href="data:text/json;charset=utf-8,..." download="foo.json">download</a>
```

The link works fine in Chrome and Firefox (the file downloads), but Safari displays the JSON in the browser window instead of downloading. I tried changing the mime-type to `application/octet-stream` but Safari still displays it instead of downloading.

Is it possible to get Safari to download this file instead of showing it **without** having all Safari users reconfigure their browser settings and hopefully without being forced to zip the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is work of the MIME types. You should change the response and send the mime type application/json

Comment: I tried that, and Safari still shows the JSON instead of downloading it.